# Obtaining IP of device without accessing Router Interface

Tags: ip

I initially posted this question in StackOverflow but I feel it may be more appropriate here.

I have an Orange Pi Zero, which I have flashed Raspbian on. It does not have HDMI, so I need to connect to it via Putty (or a similar program). The problem is that I cannot obtain the device's IP address, which seems to be a requirement in order for me to connect to it through programs like Putty.

The standard procedure for obtaining the Orange Pi's IP seems to be to log in to the admin Interface of the router, and to pull it out from there--but I am unable to do that because I am using my school's networks--and our IT Department has never had to perform anything like this, so the project has been put on hold. They told me to try "Angry IP Scanner" but I could not find my device through that program--a user also told me to try `nmap` but again, no luck with that either.

Does anyone know of any other method to obtain the device IP? One in which I do not have to login to the router's admin interface.

A friend said it is possible to link the PC to the Orange Pi via Eternet cable and connect to it like that... I can't seem to find any information for doing so, does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` (replace your local network and netmask) will ping every host and show those that respond, together with the MAC (ethernet) address. You should be able to find out your MAC address (it's usually printed on the system somewhere) so then you can find which IP address it has.

Comment: @wurtel, you should give this as an answer (even though the question is going to be closed because it's about a school network).

Answer (score 1):

Using `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` (replace your local network and netmask) will ping every host and show those that respond, together with the MAC (ethernet) address; this should always work, unless the system is firewalling the ping.

You should be able to find out the MAC address of the system (it's usually printed somewhere) so then you can find which IP address it has.

If `nmap` does not show the system because of ping being firewalled, you could still find the system via `/sbin/arp -an`, as the system should still respond to the ARP probe (ARP stands for Address Resolution Protocol, it's basically one system broadcasting on the network "who has IP wh.at.ev.er?", the system with that IP address should respond with "wh.at.ev.er is here" where "here" is its MAC address).

Comment: The ARP option will only work if they are on the same logical network/VLAN.  If, for instance, the OP is on a wireless network and the Pi is on a wired network, this may not work (most schools, at least around here, segment off the wireless from wired).

Comment: I used arp and I can see a list of devices--including my iPhone, but strangely, the Orange Pi is not showing up. Could this be because I am using an eternet cord?

Comment: The arp entry only exists for a while after its address is discovered, so it's imperative to search for the arp entry directly after doing the `nmap -sP`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, because you can connect without knowing the IP.

You can connect using the *Raspbian* default Host Name. In Putty you need to config the connection using "Host Name (or IP address)": `raspberrypi.local`

But I recommend you to switch to *[armbian](https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-zero/)* which is a better election than using *Raspbian*, I can assure you can connect using only the **hostname**.
On *armbian* the first time you need to connect with `root` user and `1234` password, after that you can configure a new user and change the root password.
In this case, in **Putty** you need to connect using *"Host Name (or IP address)*": `orangepizero.lan`

Comment: I don't know if Host Names work using a direct cable between your PC and the Orange Pi Zero.